# How to play list of mp3 files from raw folder in a loop

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have many Sound Files (.MP3) in `res/raw` folder. I want to play each file one by one.

Here is my code

```
int [] resID ={ R.raw.s1,R.raw.s2,R.raw.s3,R.raw.s4,R.raw.s5};

ArrayList<Integer> indexForMusic; 

 ..........................

 ..........................

 // on click of play button

public void playMusic(View v)
{
    for(int i:indexForMusic)
    {
        MediaPlayer  mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID[i]);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        try 
        {
             wait(1000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

but the problem is that all MP3 files are getting played simultanously, and there is no delay beteew the playing of  files..

Please tell me how can i play music one after the other?
putting wait() inside for loop is throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try thread,
something like following

```
    Thread T=new Thread(new runnable(){
    public void run(){
     MediaPlayer  mediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(this,resID[i]);
            mediaPlayer.start();
            try 
            {
                 sleep(1000);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

    }
   );
    T.start();
```

Answer (score -1):

simultaneously*, 
or try CountDownTimer

```
new CountDownTimer(1000, 100) 
{

public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                                     }
public void onFinish() {
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
}.start();
```